# Отправка сообщения ICQ средствами C#

Tags: icq, c#

Доброго времени суток!
Задался целью отправить из проекта сообщение на Юин ICQ. Документации в интернете по этому поводу нашел очень мало. Самостоятельно ничего не получилось.
Если есть у кого какие нибудь ссылки или код - запостите пожалуйста.
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Протокол ICQ немного запутан и не то что бы прост. Однако, простая отправка сообщений реализована очень просто. Вся сложность только в последовательности логина.

Самая нормальная документация, по которой мне удалось реализовать почти всё, находится [здесь](http://iserverd.khstu.ru/oscar/).

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогло))
Плюсую